# Magento 2 controller return 404 error

Tags: controllers, magento2.3.4, 404-page

C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\code\Vendor\Mymodule\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Heart_Listcolor',
    __DIR__
);
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\code\Vendor\Mymodule\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Heart_Listcolor" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\code\Vendor\Mymodule\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
<route frontName="customwishlist" id="customwishlist">
<module name="Heart_Listcolor"/>
</route>
</router>
</config>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\code\Vendor\Mymodule\Controller\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Controller\Index;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
            $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $data = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection()->getData();

        return $result->setData(['status' => 200, 'items' => $data]);
    }
}
```

url : **https://localhost/m2/customwishlist/index/wishlist** return 404 error

Comment: Did u tried https://localhost/m2/customwishlist/index url

Comment: Controller path should be `app/code/Heart/Listcolor/Controller/Index/Wishlist.php`!

Comment: @Manii It's working, thank you,

Comment: @Manii,Pawan The controller working now, i have added script under : app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Wishlist\templates\catalog\product\list\addto\wishlist.phtml
Code: https://codeshare.io/5wrl4J
If selected id available under wishlist i wan to add class name. See my script. 
Can you pls help me, the the class not added.

Comment: The custom class name not added https://snipboard.io/ktr3FN.jpg